# What the error means in react-native with android genymotion?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, promise

I am a react-native newr, and when I run react-native run-android sucuessful in genymotion, but in some stage in the app I click, it shows the error message, I know it looks some promise have no catch to make the error, but the more advanced meaning I can't reckon what happened, is there anyone knows what happened here?

```
console.error: "Unhandled promise rejection", {"line":34896,"column":24,"sourceURL":"http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false"}
error
    YellowBox.js:61
<unknown>
    es6.promise.js:117
perform
    es6.promise.js:59
<unknown>
    es6.promise.js:111
<unknown>
    JSTimers.js:100
callTimer
    JSTimersExecution.js:95
callImmediatesPass
    JSTimersExecution.js:199
callImmediates
    JSTimersExecution.js:214
<unknown>
    MessageQueue.js:214
guard
    MessageQueue.js:46
__callImmediates
    MessageQueue.js:214
<unknown>
    MessageQueue.js:128
guard
    MessageQueue.js:46
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
    MessageQueue.js:126
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows that the error happened on the javascript side of things. This is actually a warning, not an error (if you're running a debug build you will get a YellowBox instead of a red screen). It won't actually crash your app but is usually an indication that something went wrong that wasn't supposed to.

I don't know how familiar you are with javascript but basically, a JS promise can either `resolve` or `reject`, and you can specify two callback functions to handle each case. The warning you are getting means a promise completed with `reject` but no callback function was supplied to handle the rejection. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

For debugging, if the warning appeared when you tapped something in the app I would start by looking at any `onPress` callback functions and making sure that any data you're passing around looks the way you expect. At some point an asynchronous function is being called that doesn't like the data it's being passed.